# Why do I instantiate before I use

Tags: c#

I don't understand why or how I am able to instantiate a variable and assign nothing to it at the beginning of a class, but then once I get into the coding of the class, I'm able to assign it to use it.
For example in Unity I can:

```
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

// right here I can instantiate the variable...
    public int width;
    public int height;

// and then here I actually use it!!
    void GenerateMap() {
        map = new int[width,height];
        RandomFillMap();
```

Can someone please clear this up for me?

Comment: Why is this tagged `Java`?

Comment: Your not instantiating a variable, your declaring it.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong terminology. Still learning all I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSL §4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) specifies that:

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
>
> For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (byte)0.
>
> For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (short)0.
>
> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>
> For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>
> For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>
> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
>   '\u0000'.
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.
>
> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

The code you gave implicitly does this in Java:

```
public int width;
public int height;

public MapGenerator() { // Constructor
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}

void GenerateMap() {
    map = new int[width,height];
}
```

I assume C# does something similar.

Comment: This answer is for Java, even though the question is about C#

Comment: thank you so much. This helped out a lot. I was wondering about the code for C# and for Java. I wasn't sure if I was able to tag both languages since they are so similar on the beginner level, which is where I am.

Comment: @Letholor Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

[Value Types (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

> Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes
>   the default value of that type.

Notes:

- Pay attention that initializer runs only for class members.
- Local variables must be initialized before they are used.

Default Values for types:

```
bool: false
byte: 0
char: '\0'
decimal: 0.0M
double: 0.0D
enum: The value produced by the expression (E)0, where E is the enum identifier.
float: 0.0F
int: 0
long: 0L
sbyte: 0
short: 0
struct: The value produced by setting all value-type fields to their default values and all reference-type fields to null.
uint: 0
ulong: 0
ushort: 0
```

**Class Member - OK**

```
public class Sample1
{
    int i;
    public void PrintI()
    {
        //Prints 0
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Local Variable - ERROR**

```
public class Sample2
{
    public void PrintI()
    {
        int i;  
        //Compile Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between value types and reference types.

Value types (that are passed by value) are just that, values. While reference types are reference to a place where the value is.

All types have a default value, for reference types it is null which you can think of "refers to Nothing", for value types it can't be, a value can't be null, so there is a default value.

Here it works because an int is a value type, which means even unitialized it has a default value (for all number types that value is 0), if instead it was a reference type you would be getting a NullReferenceException when trying to use it uninitialized.

So for example:

```
 public class Player
 {
      public string Name;
 }

  int i; // This is the same as int i = 0 as default(int) == 0
  i.ToString(); // does not crash as i has a default value;

  Player p; // This is a reference type, the value fo default(Player) is null
  p.ToString(); // This will crash with a NullReferenceException as p was never initialized and you're effectivelly calling a method on "null".
```

Answer (score 0):

as the guys said ..there is and default value for each variable type ... and if u didn't assign any value to the variable it will be given the default value instead ...but if u like to give the variables another value in the moment of creating the object or  instantiating it you can use constructors like this

```
public class MapGenerator
{
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public MapGenerator(int Con_width, int Con_height)
    {
        width = Con_width;
        height = Con_height;
    }
}
```

now any object of the class u create must have a value for width and height

```
MapGenerator mymap = new MapGenerator(200,200);
```

now if u tried the usual object

```
  MapGenerator mymap = new MapGenerator();
```

it will give u an error because you changed this default constractor to new custom constractor